Fill entire path when using TikZ decoration
How can I extend the decoration over the entire path (top left corner of the bumpy line)? Preferably, I should match segment length to have full segments or clip the last segment.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
  \usetikzlibrary{decorations}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[thick]
            (0, 0)
            -- ++(0, -40mm)
            -- ++(30mm, 0)
            -- ++(0, 40mm);
            \draw[thick,]
            (0, -5mm)
            -- ++(0, -35mm)
            -- ++(30mm, 0)
            -- ++(0, 35mm)
            decorate[decoration={bumps, segment length=3.0mm, pre length=0mm, post length=0mm}] { -- ++(-30mm,0) };
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



This seems to be consequence to limit accuracy of tikz math,. Try to write decoration as decorate[decoration={bumps}] .

That works, but the bumps now are too pointy! Is there a way to adjust that? Thanks.

Than try with segment length=3.15 .  just a trial ...

This doesn't work in all cases for example with
\pathlength}{40mm} and {\nb}{2}, but maybe it will be enough for you.
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathmorphing}

\newlength{\pathlength}
\setlength{\pathlength}{40mm}
\newcommand{\nb}{12}% <-- *2 -->number bumps
\newcommand{\myl}{\pathlength/\nb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick]
    (0, 0)
    -- ++(0, -\pathlength)
    -- ++(\pathlength, 0)
    -- ++(0, \pathlength);
    \draw[
      thick,yshift=-5mm,
      decorate,
      decoration={bumps, 
      segment length=\myl}       
      ](\pathlength,0)--([xshift=-0.5\pgflinewidth]0.,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



This didn't work when I changed the path length!

I update my answer, I did quite a few tests, except for values ​​lower than 3 (6 bumps), it seems to work.
